# KeyListener is delaying

Tags: java

I am making FlappyBirds in java, everything works good for now. But I am stuck with a problem.

I have an integer variable called '`status`'. When `status` is `0`, the game runs, if the `status` is `1`, then the window will say "`game over, press s to begin`". My `KeyListener` works well for the game play.

But after I lose the game and `status` becomes `1`, when I press the `s` button again, I have to hold the button for sometime. It is not responding quickly. During start,the `status` is `1`. When I press the `s` during that time, it comes quickly, but when I lose and status becomes `1` again, the problem arises.

```
package flappybirds;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class FlappyBirds extends JPanel implements     ActionListener,KeyListener {
    public int WIDTH=800,HEIGHT=800,x=WIDTH/2-10,y=HEIGHT/2-10 , gravity=0,        ticks=0,status=1;
    public static FlappyBirds flappy;
    public boolean jump;
    public boolean gameOver=true ;
    public ArrayList<Rectangle>walls;
    public Rectangle bird;

    public Random generator;
    public FlappyBirds(){
        Timer t=new Timer(10,this);
        JFrame window=new JFrame("Flappy Birds");
        window.setSize(WIDTH ,HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(this);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.addKeyListener(this);
        walls=new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        generator=new Random();
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flappy=new FlappyBirds();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        bird=new Rectangle(x,y,15,15);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,200,255));
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillRect(0, HEIGHT-100, WIDTH,100);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-110,WIDTH,10);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(bird.x,bird.y,bird.width,bird.height);
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(status),200,200);
        g.setColor(new Color(200,200,40));

        if(status==0){
            for(Rectangle rect:walls){
                paintWall(rect,g);
            }
        }

        if(status==1){
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial",50,50));
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Press 'S' to begin",400,400);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();
        if(status==0){
            addWall(true);
            addWall(true);

            ticks ++;
            if(jump){
                if(ticks%8==0){
                    gravity=-10;
                }

            }
            else if(ticks%8==0 && gravity<15 && jump==false){
                gravity+=2;

            }
            if(ticks==1000){
                ticks=0;
            }
            y += gravity;

            for(Rectangle rect:walls){
                rect.x -=10;
            }

            for(int i=0;i<walls.size();i++){
                Rectangle r=walls.get(i);

                if(r.x+r.width<0){

                    addWall(false);
                }
            }


            for(Rectangle column:walls){
                if(column.intersects(bird) || bird.y>=HEIGHT-120 ||     bird.y<=3 ){
                    gameOver=true;
                    status=1;
                    if(!jump){
                        if(y>=HEIGHT-120){
                            y=HEIGHT-120;
                        }
                        if(column.intersects(bird)){
                            y=HEIGHT/2-10;
                        }
                        if(bird.y<=3){
                            y=HEIGHT/2-10;
                        }
                    }else if(jump){
                        y=HEIGHT/2-10;
                    }
                }else{
                    gameOver=false;
                }
            }
            collide();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c=e.getKeyCode();
        if(status==0){
            if(c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                jump=true;
            }
        }
        if(status==1){
            if(c==KeyEvent.VK_S){

                status=0;
            }
        }
    }
    public void collide(){
        if(status==0){
            if(gameOver){
                walls.clear();
                addWall(true);
                addWall(true);
                gameOver=false;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        jump=false;
    }
    public void paintWall(Rectangle rect,Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
    public void paintSpace(Rectangle rect,Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(0,200,225));
        g.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.width,rect.height);
    }
    public void addWall(boolean oldwall){
        int width=100;
        final int height=350;
        int yloc=100+generator.nextInt(150);
        int space=100;
        if(oldwall){
            if( generator.nextBoolean()){
                walls.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH+width+    (walls.size()*200),HEIGHT- height-yloc,width,height));
                walls.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH+width+(walls.size()-1)*200,-    yloc, width,height- space));
            }else{
                walls.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH+width+    (walls.size()*200),HEIGHT-height+yloc,width,height));
                walls.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH+width+    (walls.size()-1)*200,+yloc, width,height- space));
            }
        }else{
            if( generator.nextBoolean()){
                walls.add(new     Rectangle(walls.get(walls.size()-1).x+600,HEIGHT-height-    yloc,width,height+space));
                walls.add(new Rectangle(walls.get(walls.size()-2).x+600,-    yloc,width,height-space));
            }else{
                walls.add(new     Rectangle(walls.get(walls.size()-1).x+600,HEIGHT-    height+yloc,width,height+space));
                walls.add(new     Rectangle(walls.get(walls.size()-2).x+600,yloc,width,height-space));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not really enough information to answer your question. There is nothing wrong with the piece of code you showed, which means the problem comes from somewhere else. Maybe your game loop takes up too much memory during the second time or your code that switches to the game itself is only reached after some sort of delay or your Key Listener gets removed and reassigned after a while, i could go on and on with random possibilities but with so little information, I don't think it will help.

Comment: Can I post the whole source code?

Comment: I guess you could, though that's likely to be A LOT of code to read through and not a lot of people will find the time for that :D It would probably be better if you could try debugging a little so you can figure out roughly where in your code your problems lie and then only post those parts. Simply use the debugger of your ide or put in some test output (just remember to take it out again afterwards). I'd probably start of by seeing if the keyPressed method is called too late or the piece of code that needs to be executed once status is 0.

Comment: As I am not able to find the exact error, even after debugging, I am going to paste the whole source code, Thanks for you effort.

Comment: The game is called "Flappy Bird" not "Flappy Birds". I don't know why but a lot of people mix that up! It would help everyone a lot if you formatted your code properly before posting it. Additionally, there is a lot of clutter... reduce the problem to the few lines of code that matter.

Comment: Oh, I get it, Let me try to find the heart of the error and format the code properly. I am a newbie to this SO and only I know mediocre java.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the cause of the delay is the timer:

The timer is running continuously, launching events every 10ms (i.e. invoking `actionPerformed`). **Even after the game is over it is running**, so the ActionEvent events get accumulated in the event queue and the 'S' you press suffers a big delay until its turn comed to be processed.

I recommend you:

1. Stop the timer as soon as the game is over.
2. As soon as the game is re-started, re-initialize all the instance variables to their initial state. For example, implement a private method called `init` and take there the initialization of `x`, `y`, `gravity`, `ticks`, `walls`, and of course, the call to `timer.start()`.
3. Call `init` at the end of the constructor and also within `keyPressed`, after letting `status=0`.

Comment: Should i stop the timer in the constructor? I am asking this because when I do so, it is not working.

Comment: No. The timer must be started in the constructor, and stopped when you assign `gameOver=true`.